# Laravel Add a filter to resourceful route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, filter, routes

I'm using Laravel 4.2
I have a ressourceful route like this:

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');
```

How can I add a filter, let's say '**auth**' filter to all corresponding routes and how to target only some of them, let's say I want only to filter access to the named route '**customers.create**'.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a filter in your Controller's constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', ['only' => ['update', 'store']]);
}
```

If you have many resources you can use route groups:

```
Route::group(['before'=>'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');
    // ... another resource ...
});
```

...and specify beforeFilter in each Controller's constructor.

**OR:**

- Use a simple *if* statement in routes.php:

  ```
  if (Auth::check()) {
      Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController');
  } else {
      Route::resource('customers', 'CustomersController', ['except' => ['update', 'store']]);
  }
  ```
- Create a *base controller* for resources that use the same filter and extend it:

  ```
  class AuthorizedController extends BaseController {
      // ... constructor with beforeFilter definition ...
  }

  class CustomersController extends AuthorizedController { ... }
  ```